# Android ListView Error when i run

Tags: android, android-listview

i am beginner android developer and i want help me!
i want when i click the page icon and Intent start show my data who save into Offer table
i write this code in android studio:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_froyo);
        //setHeader(getString(R.string.FroyoActivityTitle), true, true);
        String[] myOffers=new String[20];
        int counter=0;




        SQLiteDatabase myDB=openOrCreateDatabase("MYOFFER",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM offer", null);
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        String myCID = null;
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            //myCID=c.getString(0);
            myOffers[counter]=c.getString(0);
            Log.d("my Offer=",c.getString(0));
            Log.d("And Counter=", String.valueOf(counter));
            counter++;

        }
        //String[] countryArray = {"India", "Pakistan", "USA", "UK"};

        ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myOfferList);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.offershow, myOffers);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
```

and when run the project get this error:

```
01-31 08:34:38.972    1080-1080/com.technotalkative.viewstubdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
```

and when i replace this line:

```
String[] countryArray = {"India", "Pakistan", "USA", "UK"};

        ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myOfferList);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.offershow, countryArray);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my project work finally!,but what happen?

Comment: dump your activity_froyo xml layout

Comment: how can i do this?please more explain to me,thanks my friend to attention my problem @codehx

Comment: what I mean is post your `activity_froyo` xml  so we can see it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

> ```
>     String[] myOffers=new String[20];
> ```

Probably `myOffers` some items are `null` so Adapter showing `NullPointerException`. Use `c.getCount()` to define Array size:

```
    Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM offer", null);
    String[] myOffers=new String[c.getCount()];
```